# Is there a way I can map the keys of an object to render keys of a nested object as a list under its respective category

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: The object structure]

Expected output sample

```
**Car**<br>
Volvo<br>
Mazda

**Confectionaries** <br>
Cake<br>
Candy

**Food** <br>
Rice <br>
Beans
```

Is there a way I can map the keys of an object in this case (car, confectionaries, food e.t.c) to output the keys of a nested object( in this case Volvo, Mazda for car e.tc)  as a list under its respective category

Note: This is a project I am working on presently to improve my Reactjs skills, any suggestion on how to better fast track my learning process is highly welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

> The `Object.entries()` method returns an array of a given object's own
>   enumerable string-keyed property `[key, value]` pairs.

```
Object.entries(state.categories).map(([key, value]) => (/* render JSX */));
```

```js
const state = {
  categories: {
    car: {
      volvo: 1,
      mazsa: 2
    },
    confectionary: {
      cake: 1,
      candy: 2
    },
    food: {
      rice: 1,
      beans: 2
    }
  }
};

// sorry, this is fugly, but actual JSX is cleaner
const res = Object.entries(state.categories)
  .map(([key, category]) => `<ul key={${key}}>${
    Object.entries(category)
      .map(([key, item]) => `\n  <li key={${key}}>${item}</li>`).join('')
  }\n</ul>`).join('\n');

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Use a second `Object.keys(value).map(key => (/* JSX */)` to render the inner values...

Comment: @faceman yes, was working on running code snippet right then ;)

Answer (score 0):

```js
    let categories= {
      car:{
        volvo:1,
        mazsa:2
      },
      confectionary:{
        cake:1,
        candy:2
      },
      food:{
        rice:1,
        beans:2
      }
    }

    for (let key1 in categories){
        console.log(key1);
      for(let key2 in categories[key1]){
        console.log('\t',key2);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel you want to get an object values from a set of given keys
1- use [`Object.keys(/* object name */)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the original object keys.
2- use [`map()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) function to render the output
all in all would be:

```
Object.keys(categories.car).map( ( key ) => categories.confectionaries[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get my list items into an array which can be mapped into its different ul component using this piece of code

const ul =

```
        Object.entries(props.allshop).map(([item, list,index]) => {

           [...Array(Object.keys(list))]
         .map((newItem, index) => {


          return <BuildControl key={index} item={newItem} title={item}></BuildControl>

        })   

        })
```

However, I still have an issue because ul is returning undefined as the values of the array like this

{console.log(ul)} = [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]

I tried running console.log on my BuildControl component and it returned the objects I was expecting like this :
console.log (  )

[console.log (  )
reveals the arrays mapped correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpJJG.png)

Now my challenge is how to get the ul to return this value of the buildControl insteadof undefined